# Facebook API - get watched movie rating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In facebook you can rate movies you watched with a five-star rating. Is there anyway to get this rating using Graph API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accessed via the

```
GET /me/video.rates
```

endpoint. See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.rates/#read for the documentation. As far as I know you need the **"user_actions.video"** permission, althought this is not explicitly stated in the permission docs below https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-opengraph

Comment: Any idea how to query data for just one type of video rates? like type='video.movie'